# Is it possible to apply Minecraft Mods to a single 'world'?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods

I'm going to get Minecraft when I have a better computer in order to run it, and I've seen some really interesting mods out there for it.  What I want to know is if I can set mods to only run on a specific generated world.

IE say I have 2 mods installed.  Is it possible to have a world with just one or the other or even neither of them?  I don't want to be finding tin or oil from Galacticraft if I'm doing some kind of fantasy RPG type game, for instance.

I appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: You can create a game profile and set its paths. Then if you want Just create a new profile for each setup. The loader still needs to be set to load forge which then loads the native. But forge will see the set path and looks for mods in the path/mods folder.

Comment: It’s not per world but it’s the closest thing. You can create a single world and it’s the same thing.

Comment: @ydobonebi That's already the answer. Can you please write it as one?

Comment: Fun fact: Exactly this "mods set per world" is planned with the plugin API. But we'll likely still have to wait a long time for that.

Comment: @ydobonebi That sounds like a solution, and if you propose it as such, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ydobonebi in a comment

You can create a game profile and set its paths. Then if you want Just create a new profile for each setup. The loader still needs to be set to load forge which then loads the native. But forge will see the set path and looks for mods in the path/mods folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to disable mods in the Forge Mod Loader, but otherwise, **no**, you cannot set different mod settings for one world over another.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have mod-specific worlds when using the same launcher (i.e. the same file path), however, the way modpack managers get around the issue of running multiple mods is by having separate instances of Minecraft for the different Modpacks. So, you can either run a second instillation of Minecraft, and have that as the modded one with modded worlds in it, or, you can try and find your desired modifications in a Modpack Managers (Such as FTB, Technic, ATLauncer).